# Why can't I access my Controller even though I've configured antMatchers in Spring Security?

Tags: spring-security

Can someone help me?

`TestController`

```java
@RestController
public class Test {
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<String > test(){
        System.out.println("Response body: " + "hello");
        return ResponseEntity.ok(" hello ");
    }
}
```

[image: Postman]

`SecurityConfig`

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    public static final String[] EXCLUDE_PATH = {
            "/webjars/**",
            "/favicon.ico",
            "/captcha",
            "/user/login",
            "/user/logout",
            "/test"
    };
    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint).and()

                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(EXCLUDE_PATH).permitAll() 
                .anyRequest().authenticated()

             
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

        ;

        return http.build();
    }


    @Bean
    WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return webSecurity -> {
            webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers(EXCLUDE_PATH);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Http 200 seems ok (regarding security (matcher)), but (regarding  strange response) your `response.setContenttype` (jpeg) is not consistent with what you respond(looks like json)..hi & welcome! (Did the endpoint work without security?;)

Comment: Thank you.@xerx593 I'm sure it's not a problem with `response.setContentType`. When security is removed, the data can be returned normally. Therefore, I think it's possible that the security filter chain has processed my response in some way, causing an empty data to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

What's confusing is that when I created a new Spring Boot project and migrated the original project over, the problem was solved. This confirmed that there was no problem with my Security configuration, but I was still puzzled by this situation.